# SCNPhysicsBodyType from Static to Dynamic - Swift

Tags: xcode, swift

Using Swift in Xcode:

I want a SCNPhysicsBody to start as SCNPhysicsType.Static and then later I want it to be Dynamic, but changing it seems to have no effect on the SCCNode. How can I change from Static to Dynamic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the `type` property on `SCNPhysicsBody` is indeed read/write, I'm not sure it's really intended to be used that way. It's possible that it's not doing anything to the underlying physics simulation when you change it.

It might be better to remove the static body from the node and replace it with a new dynamic body. Or, depending on what you wanted a static body for, keep the body dynamic and use its other properties to keep it still until it needs to move. (For example, if you want to keep it from falling or being affected by collisions, set its `velocityFactor` and `angularVelocityFactor` properties to zero vectors, then change them when you want to make the body "live".)

Comment: affectedByGravity would be very useful but it appears that this isnt a property of SCNPhysicsBody (it is available for SCNParticleSystem and SKPhysicsBody). Im now trying out adding the SCNPhysicsBody at a later time after initialising the SCNNode but in the simulator the SCNNode momentarily appears in a random place before jumping back to it's original place and applying the physics.

Comment: Whoops, getting SK and SCN confused again. :) See edited answer for  better example.